# Angular ngModel doesn't fire Kendo change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a [Kendo model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model) instance (`person` for this example) and watching it is modified or not by using `dirty` property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo + Angular</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>Person name: {{ person.name }}</div>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="person.name"> <!-- This input don't work -->
    <button ng-click="foo()">Foo</button> <!-- This button work because I call person.set method manually -->
    <div>This person is modified? {{ person.dirty }}</div>
</div>
<script>
    var Person = kendo.data.Model.define({
        id: "personId", // the identifier of the model
        fields: {
            "name": {
                type: "string"
            },
            "age": {
                type: "number"
            }
        }
    });

    angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"])
            .controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.person = new Person({
                    name: "John Doe",
                    age: 42
                });
                $scope.foo = function () {
                    $scope.person.set('name', "Kendo");
                }
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I type to text box `dirty` don't change because Angular ngModel doesn't fire Kendo "change" event. My real app have dozens of models like this, so is there any way to fix this automatically???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a directive to replace for ng-model,

```
<input type="text" name="name" k-bind-model="person.name">



angular.module('app')
    .directive("kBindModel", ["$parse", function ($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: false,
                link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {


                    var key = null;
                    var strs = attributes.kBindModel.split('.');
                    if (strs && strs.length > 1) {
                        key = strs[1];
                    }

                    var     model = scope[strs[0]];

                    element.change(function () {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            model.set(key, element.val());
                        });
                    });

                    scope.$watch(attributes.kBindModel, function (n, o) {
                        element.val(n);
                    });


                }
            }
        }]);
```